# Pasar distintos valores desde el mismo button

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Básicamente estoy cambiando una pantalla desde donde tenia 4 inputs y 4 buttons ( cada input asociado a un button por cada ) . En el evento Onclick del button llamaba a un jquery que llama a un php para mostrar una imagende acuerdo al criterio establecido en los parametros que le envio :

```html
onclick="mostrar_imagen(document.getElementById('por_numero').value,'','','1');"
```

Esto funcionaba. Actualmente armé un menú horizontal, en el q tengo  2 items con subitem que muestran un input y requieren ingreso de un valor, 1 item sin subitem que muestra tambien un input de ingreso, y todos los demas items que al clickear ejecutan los criterios ya establecidos en el codigo.
No encuentro la forma de usar el mismo input y button y pasar distintos valores a la funcion que llama al PHP. Paso 4 criterios a la funcion mostrar_imagen. Espero se entienda. 
Copio el código, espero vuestra ayuda !

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

        function mostrar_imagen(num,nom,sec,otro) {
            document.getElementById('carga_img').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('boton_x').style.display='block';

            var ruta="plano_de_imagen.php?num="+num+"&nom="+nom+"&sec="+sec+"&otro="+otro;
            $("#carga_imagen").load(ruta);
        };

     function nomostrar_volver() {
         document.getElementById('carga_img').style.display='none';
         document.getElementById('boton_x').style.display='none';
     };

    </script>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="contenedor">
  <nav id="menu">
    <li id="nav_mobile">Menú <img src="ham.png" style="width: 16px; margin-bottom: -3px"></li>
    <div id="oculto">
     <li><a href="#" id="inicio" >Inicio</a></li>
     <li>Busca Foto <img src="flechita.png" width="13" height="12">
      <ul style="display:none">
          <li><a class="opciones" id="por_numero" href="#">Por ID</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="por_nombre" href="#">Por Nombre</a></li>        
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a id="por_seccion" href="#">Busca x Sector</a></li>
     <li>Habilitados <img src="flechita.png" width="13" height="12">
      <ul style="display:none">
          <li><a class="opciones" id="01" href="#">Sector01</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="02" href="#">Sector02</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="03" href="#">Sector03</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="04" href="#">Sector04</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="05" href="#">Sector05</a></li>
          <li><a class="opciones" id="06" href="#">Sector06</a></li>          
       </ul>
     </li>
    </div>    
  </nav>

  <div id="cabeza">
   <div id="marco">
    <span id="nombre_campo">Ingrese el Nº : </span><input type="number" id="cajita" name="ingreso" autofocus>
    <input type="button" id="boton1" name="enviar" onclick="mostrar_imagen(document.getElementById('por_numero').value,'','','1');" value="Buscar">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    
 <div id="carga_img"></div>
 <a href="#" id="boton_x" class="botonx" style="display:none;" onclick="javascript:nomostrar_volver();">X</a>

  
 </div>

 <script>

 //Desplegar al hacer clic
 $('#menu li').click(function(){ 
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast'); 
 });

 $('#nav_mobile').click(function(){ 
  $('#oculto').slideToggle('fast'); 
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#inicio').click(function(){
   $('#cabeza').css('display', 'none');
  });

     $('#por_numero').click(function(){
      $('#cabeza').css('display', 'Block');
         $('span#nombre_campo').text('Ingrese el Nº : ');
         $('#cajita').focus();
     }); 

     $('#por_nombre').click(function(){
      $('#cabeza').css('display', 'Block');
         $('span#nombre_campo').text('Ingrese el Nombre : ');
         $('#cajita').focus();
     }); 

     $('#por_seccion').click(function(){
   if($('#cabeza').css('display') == 'none')
   {
       $('#cabeza').css('display', 'Block');
          $('span#nombre_campo').text('Ingrese Nº del Sector : ');
          $('#cajita').focus();
   }else {
    $('#cabeza').css('display', 'none');
   }
     }); 

     $('#01').click(function(){
      $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
     }); 

     $('#02').click(function(){
      $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
     }); 

     $('#03').click(function(){  
         $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
     }); 

     $('#04').click(function(){
         $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
     }); 

     $('#05').click(function(){
         $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
     }); 
     
        $('#06').click(function(){
         $('#cabeza').css('display', 'None');
        });

 });  

 </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu planteamiento no es muy claro, lo único que he entendido es que quieres pasar varios valores a través del click de un botón.

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto y todo dependerá de tu aplicación. Puedes por ejemplo tener `inputs` de la misma clase que ese botón donde recojas las datos y al hacer click en el botón se recojan los valores de los inputs de esa clase.

Esto sería particularmente útil cuando el usuario tenga que escribir explícitamente los valores. Entonces dispondrías de cada `input` para decirle al usuario qué datos tiene que escribir.

Veamos un ejemplo de grupos de `input` por clases y botones. Aquí hay dos grupos que son escuchados de forma independiente según se presione un botón un otro. Por simplicidad he asignado la misma función al click de cada botón. Si se necesita se puede asignar una función distinta a cada clic del botón, agrupando en ese caso directamente por la clase más particular de los divs, o sea, por las clases `grupo1` y `grupo2`:

```js
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".estudiante button");

allButtons.forEach(function(btn) {

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var selector = `.${this.name} input`;
    var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    allInputs.forEach(function(input) {
      var test = `${input.name} : ${input.value}`;
      console.log(test);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="estudiante">
  <div class="grupo1">
    <input type="text" name="ibxName" placeholder="Escriba el nombre" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="ibxApellido" placeholder="Escriba el apellido" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="ibxCiudad" placeholder="Escriba la ciudad" />
    <br />
    <button id="boton1" name="grupo1">Acción Grupo 1</button>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="grupo2">
    <input type="text" name="ibxProfesor" placeholder="Escriba el profesor" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="ibxAsignatura" placeholder="Escriba asignatura" />
    <br />
    <button id="boton2" name="grupo2">Acción Grupo 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Otra forma de pasar múltiples valores es por medio de los atributos `data*`. Esto puede ser particularmente útil cuando se quiere pasar valores fijos (en los cuales el usuario no interviene de una forma directa). O sea, no es lo mismo que un `input`. Pero no quiere decir que sean valores estáticos. Los atributos `data` se pueden cambiar. Pensemos por ejemplo en un valor de stock donde en cada click se descuenta un elemento. La existencia puede estar en el atributo `data` y cada vez que se agrega un artículo al carrito, este atributo se puede disminuir en uno y actualizarlo.

Aquí muestro un ejemplo donde, en el mismo botón guardamos tres informaciones distintas a través de los atributos `data`. Al hacer click en el botón podemos recuperar por separado el valor de cada uno de esos atributos.

Así como lo hacemos con un botón, lo podemos hacer con un `input` o con cualquier otro elemento. Los atributos data son utilísimos para guardar información que no se necesita presentar en pantalla, o para guardar información estructurada que se recupera y/o actualiza de forma dinámica.

```js
var btnData = document.getElementById('btnData');
btnData.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var dataSet = this.dataset;
  console.log(dataSet);
  console.log(dataSet.name);
  console.log(dataSet.lastname);
  console.log(dataSet.age);
});
```

```html
<button id="btnData" data-name="Pedro" data-lastname="Pérez" data-age="24">Mostrar Datos</button>
```

Espero que ambas posibilidades te sean de utilidad.

> **NOTA:** En el código he dado preferencia a código Javascript puro. Es conveniente hacerlo siempre que se pueda, evitando así el uso de
>   librerías externas que ralentizan la ejecución, como es natural.

Comment: Genial ... resuelto con el atributo data. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te envío una respuesta que espero te sirva de referencia:

Primero te aconsejo que no hagas la llamada de la función en el evento "onclick" y mejor hazla desde un .js externo o dentro de un bloque "script" que este dentro de tu pagina, para que el código que te sugiero funcione primero reemplaza:

```
<input type="button" id="boton1" name="enviar" onclick="mostrar_imagen(document.getElementById('por_numero').value,'','','1');" value="Buscar">
```

por esto:

```
<input type="button" id="boton1" name="enviar" value="Buscar">
```

Dentro de un bloque "script" agrega esto y modifica los selectores por los tuyos:

```
<script>
    // al hacer click en el botón ejecutar la función:
    $('.boton1').click(function(){
        // obtener los valores de los diferentes selectores que necesites
        var valor1 = $('#por_numero').val();
        var valor2 = $('#selector').val();
        var valor3 = $('#selector2').val();
        var valor4 = $('#selector3').val();
        // enviarlos a la funcion que deseas que los procese
        mostrar_imagen(valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4);
        // con esto debería funcionar como quieres
    });
</script>
```

saludos.